# How to connect to Couchbase Lite REST API

Tags: rest, couchbase-lite

Couchbase Lite documentation (semi-docs!) mention this about connecting to the REST API:

> Provides native, object-oriented APIs for iOS and Android devices that
>   integrate with your app framework. These APIs can map database
>   documents to your own native object model, let you work directly with
>   JSON structures, or both. Additionally, apps built with web
>   technologies can use the Couchbase Lite REST API (for example,
>   JavaScript, C#, or Python applications).

Is this only in the context of PhoneGap and similar techs that would provide their own listeners, or is there some kind of a generic lite server wrapper that would make the CBL REST API accessible in any context?! (This is what REST implies I guess).

Worded differently, is it for example possible to connect from Python to CBL using REST in any context (with available libs/tools of course), or is that not possible?

(I understand the difference between **Couchbase Lite** and **Couchbase Server** so that's not what I'm asking about, I'm strictly talking about Couchbase Lite).

Comment: If it is REST it will be an open API and you can use it through any means that supports rest.

Comment: CBL is an embedded lib similar to Sqlite, not a a server, hence the question on how to connect to it through REST.

Comment: Curious on your use case with Python and CBL ?

Comment: Not a real use case so to speak, I was modelling part of an (Android) app in Python because I thought NOSQL is a better fit for it, but I hit a few issues with that.

Answer (score 1):

You can create your own wrapper and include the CBL RESTful APIs:  http://developer.couchbase.com/mobile/develop/references/couchbase-lite/rest-api/index.html

Comment: Hey @Andy,  I have updated the URL just now and thanks for pointing it out!

Answer (score 0):

Here is a usable reference using Cordova/ionic and a TypeScript API for the CBL REST API. You can take a look here [cordova-plugin-couchbase-lite](https://github.com/happieio/cordova-plugin-couchbase-lite) or on [npm](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-plugin-couchbase-lite)

There is an example project embedded in the test folder to see how it integrates.

Both are written in Typescript, so the source would need to be compiled to use in a JS project. The test app is configured to generate the JS for you if need be.